# how to select distinct values from two different tables

Tags: sql, distinct-values

I have two tables like 
table1:

```
id   name   posId   Mid
1    sam    1       10
2    sid    1       10
3    jeet   1       10
```

table2:

```
id   name   posid   Mid
1    Anin   2       10
2    Nir    2       10
3    jeev   2       10
```

I want to have a table like...

```
posid
1
2
```

ie; i want to have distinct "posid" by joining table1 and table2 where "Mid" will be same for table1 and table2

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are  using.

Comment: Add a few  more rows with sample data, and adjust the expected result accordingly. (And make proper columns.)

Comment: What is "where Mid will be same for table1 and table2" supposed to mean? Your result contains no `Mid` and in your sample data all records have `Mid = 10`. Are you particularily looking for all `posId` where `Mid = 10` or something else?

Comment: Always post a detailed question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want distinct `posid` from both tables.

This isnt efficient but works:

```
select distinct aa.posid
from
    (select distinct table1.posid as posid
       from table1
       join table2
         on table1.mid=table2.mid
     UNION ALL
     select distinct table2.posid as posid
       from table1
       join table2
         on table1.mid=table2.mid) aa
```

Comment: what would happen to the data where rows are empty ? Please add some comments/description  to your answer

Comment: i tried this one and got an error ie;Ambiguous column name 'posid'.

Comment: @SamarJeetBorah you should not get that error, if u select columns properly i.e `table1.posid` and `table2.posid`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
select distinct t1.posId
from t1
where not exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.posId = t1.posId)
union all
select distinct t2.posId
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t2.posId = t1.posId);
```

I think I misinterpeted the question.  You can use `join`:

```
select t1.posid, t2.posid
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.mid = t2.mid;
```

To get this as a column, you need to unpivot.  Here is one method:

```
select distinct (case when n.which = 1 then t1.posid else t2.posid end) as posid
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.mid = t2.mid cross join
     (select 1 as which union all select 2 as which) n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` with `union`

```
select t1.posid
from t1 join t2 on t1.mid = t2.mid
union
select t2.posid
from t1 join t2 on t1.mid = t2.mid
```