# Query to avoid the repeated values from two tables

Tags: sql-server

TABLE_1

```
ID   NAME
1    CAR
2    ANIMAL
5    ROCK
```

TABLE_2

```
ID   NAME
1    GRASS
2    ROCKET
3    STONE
4    DOG
```

I want my query to return unique ID values from both tables:

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide more detail about your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to select distinct values from two different tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49732525/how-to-select-distinct-values-from-two-different-tables)

Comment: @xdtTransform no i want all the values but dont need to repeate them

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sql  server

Comment: Then I'll leave my answer up as one other way to do this without using a union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `union`

```
select id from table1
union 
select id from table2
```

Comment: thanks @fahmi i want to get it by using sub query

Comment: @why, do u've any special requirement

Comment: @fahmin i just want to know another way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You could use a full outer join here:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID)
FROM TABLE_1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_2 t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
ORDER BY
    COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID);
```

This assumes you are using SQL Server (and not MySQL).